# Scale and Translate a parabola to a golden distribution(which is also parabolic)

Tags: curve-fitting

I have multiple image histograms(difference images) whose distribution is parabolic.I use least squares to do a quadratic fit .The questions is how do I scale and translate this parabola to a golden curve (also parabolic)

Comment: What's a "golden curve"? Please offer an explicit definition.

Comment: My Y axis is in log scale and X axis is between 0-255 (GL of the images in a 8 bit system).My golden curve is a parabola which intersects X axis at 30 and Y axis at 2^20 . Now i want to equalize the distribution of the difference images through scaling and translation to the golden parabola mentioned here.

Comment: By the term "a golden curve", might you mean "a reference curve"?

Comment: Indeed.I mean a reference curve